# Particular Solution for $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-\frac{1}{x^2}y=x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I cannot find a particular solution to this ODE. I tried $ax^2+bx+c$ which was my first guess inspired by $x^2$ which is the forcing function

$y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-\frac{1}{x^2}y=x^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like $$y(x) = x^4$$

That way, when you take two derivatives, you're left with terms that are all multiples of $x^2$.

---

Specifically, if $y(x) = x^4$ then
$$y^{\prime\prime} + \frac{1}{x}y^\prime - \frac{1}{x^2}y = 12x^2 + 4x^2 -x^2 = 15x^2 $$

So we've got to scale our solution to:

$$y(x) = \frac{x^4}{15}$$

Comment: But can you find the _general_ solution?

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't asked for it. $y(x) = c_1 \frac{x^2+1}{x} + c_2 \frac{i}{2} \frac{x^2-1}{x} + \frac{x^4}{15}$.